# do something foreach Index in a Range

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable, c#-8.0

C# 8.0 introduced the structs `System.Index` and `System.Range`

What is the most concise way to loop through a `System.Range`?

```cs
var owners = new string[] {"Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"};
var pets = new string[] {"Dog", "Cat", "Bird"};

foreach (var index in 1..3) {
    var pet = pets[index];
    var owner = owners[index];
    Console.WriteLine($"{owner} owns a {pet}");
}
```

The above line `foreach (var index in 1..3) {` is a compile error.

> Type 'System.Range' cannot be used in 'foreach' statement because it neither implements 'IEnumerable' or 'IEnumerable', nor has suitable 'GetEnumerator' method which return type has 'Current' property and 'MoveNext' method

Comment: It is worth noting that this particular coding structure is known as the anti-pattern ["parallel collections"](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). Consider refactoring to use Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Btw the use of two arrays is only for showing a use-case. It is there to communicate that 'just use a for loop' is not a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't enumerate a `System.Range`(you can, see my edit) because it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<int>`. The reason is that it could contain indexes from the end of a collection.

If you want that you need to use a `for`-loop or `Enumerable.Range`:

```
foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(0, 3)) {
    var pet = pets[index];
    var owner = owners[index];
    Console.WriteLine($"{owner} owns a {pet}");
}
```

If all you want is to get the items of two collections at the same index use `Enumerable.Zip` as [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70225161/284240) has shown.

---

Edit: Actually you *can* do it with an extension(credits [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2306), note my bugfix)

```
public static class RangeEx
{
    public static RangeEnumerator GetEnumerator(this Range range)
    {
        if (range.Start.IsFromEnd || range.End.IsFromEnd)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(range));
        }

        return new RangeEnumerator(range.Start.Value, range.End.Value);
    }

    public struct RangeEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
    {
        private readonly int _end;
        private int _current;

        public RangeEnumerator(int start, int end)
        {
            _current = start - 1; // - 1 fixes a bug in the original code
            _end = end;
        }

        public int Current => _current;
        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public bool MoveNext() => ++_current < _end;

        public void Dispose() { }
        public void Reset()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can use your code:

```
foreach (int index in 1..3)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{owners[index]} owns a {pets[index]}");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to enumerate `(owner, pet)` tuples you can do it with a help of *Linq* [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) instead of `Range`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

foreach (var (owner, pet) in owners.Zip(pets, (o, p) => (o, p))) {
  Console.WriteLine($"{owner} owns a {pet}");
}
```

If you want to `Skip` the very 1st owner (Alice) and her pet (`Dog`) just add `Skip` (in your code you have range starting from `1`, not from `0`):

```
foreach (var (owner, pet) in owners.Zip(pets, (o, p) => (o, p)).Skip(1)) {
  Console.WriteLine($"{owner} owns a {pet}");
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I literally want to loop over a `System.Range`  as the codebase I'm working with is already using a lot of ranges and indexes. Can Linq do this?

Comment: @Troy: if you have to work with `System.Range` you have to use extensions method(s), please have a look at *Tim Schmelter's* answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use foreach loop with Range since it doesn't implement IEnumerable interface. You can only use Range  if you want to show a part of array for example

```
Range range = 0..2;

var i=range.Start.Value;
foreach (var owner in owners[range])
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{owner} owns a {pets[i]}");
    i++;
}
```

result

```
Alice owns a Dog
Bob owns a Cat
```

or

```
Range range = 1..3;

var i=range.Start.Value;
foreach (var owner in owners[range])
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{owner} owns a {pets[i]}");
    i++;
}
```

result

```
Bob owns a Cat
Charlie owns a Bird
```

but in your case it is much easier to use for loop

```
for (var i=0; i <3; i++) Console.WriteLine($"{owners[i]} owns a {pets[i]}");
```